# Why an <img> is larger than flex-basis (with flex-grow 0)

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using `flexbox` and I just realised that in a specific image I have `flex: 0 0 125px;` but the image visible `width` is `200px`.
If I make the `flex-basis` bigger than the image intrinsic `width` it keeps the `flex-basis` size but if I use a `flex-basis` smaller than its' intrinsic-size it keeps the intrinsic-size and doesn't shrink to the `flex-basis`.
Basically:
`<img>` is `200px` intrinsic `width`;
`flex: 0 0 250px` --- `img` visible `width` = `250px`;
`flex: 0 0 150px` --- `img` visible `width` = `200px`;
`flex: 0 0 100px` --- `img` visible `width` = `200px`;
`width: 150px` --- `img` visible `width` = `150px`;
If I use `width` it always works.
Can someone explain or point an explanation, please.

Comment: An initial setting of a flex item is `min-width: auto`. That means that, by default, a flex item cannot be smaller than the size of it's content. Add `min-width: 0` to override the default.

Comment: you can also add / try img {margin:auto} among your tests :)

Comment: @Michael_B. This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. I'm trying to use `flex`on every html element that `display: flex`except for fixed or absolute positioned elements. I think it is more pure than use `width`but with ìmg` if I use `width`it looks simpler than `flex: 0 0 120px`and `min-width: 0`. Do you have an opinion? (PS: turn your comment into an answer please, so that I can accept it).

Comment: @GCyrillus. Thank you! It's great but I was looking for the specs explanation that I was missing.

Comment: @Michael_B. Sorry. My googling didn't catch that question. thank you again.

Comment: Even if you use `width` instead of `flex-basis`, the element is still a flex item. That means that `min-width: auto` should still apply. I would not rely on `width` always working to solve this problem. It would be safe to add `min-width: 0` to flex items when you want them to shrink below the content size.

Comment: I don't think there's a need to post a new answer here. I think my answer in the duplicate addresses the issue completely. But let me know if you disagree or have questions.

Comment: @Michael_B. No, no. I agree. Your other answer is totally clear (I just didn't find it previously). BTW as a coincidence I've read a few answers from you regarding flexbox and grid css as I'm evaluating changing from flexbox to grid as a main display standard. Nevertheless (as a sidenote) I'll keep flexbox only as it has the huge advantage of avoiding plenty of media queries due to its auto responsiveness. really appreciate your support to everyone. Huge thanks Michael!